# Where to download GlassFish maintainance packs?

Tags: java, glassfish

My project was considering to use GlassFish as the Java EE 7.0 AppServer. I just moved from WebSphere, quite unfamiliar with GlassFish.

Today I tried creating a jdbc connection  pool in the GlassFish console, which yielded a RuntimeException. After a little googling I learnt that it's a known bug since 201512 but still occurrs on my most recently downloaded V4.1.1. I think I need to upgrade it.

Is there a place for downloading GlassFish maintanance packs? I tried but have got no luck so far.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you add the GlassFish bug you found? The answer below has recommended Payara Server so I expect it would be fixed there, but I could check for you if I knew the bug. (I work for Payara)

Comment: the bug is quite easily recreated. Just try to create a datasource/connection pool, it will throw a RuntimeException... for V4.1.1.

Comment: thanks for the attention. I've moved to OGS. It doesn't really matter for the version to be lower. I want it to be stable. I've been quite accustomed to WebSphere's style...

Comment: Stability is the reason for Payara Server, hence the high focus on fixing GlassFish bugs. Oracle GlassFish Server (3.1.2.2) is Java EE 6, there is no Java EE 7 release. WebSphere has a Java EE 7 release in the Liberty profile, though I think that's very different to full WAS. Do be aware that Oracle GlassFish Server is **not** free and a license is required to use it in production. Payara Server is completely free and open source.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll look into it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle does not actively support GlassFish (they want everyone to migrate to WebLogic) so there's more googling for you on any of less encountered bugs. Have you considered [Paraya Server](http://www.payara.fish/)? It's a fork of GlassFish and they maintain it actively. I've never used it but it seems more stable.

Comment: I'm going for Paraya today. Hah... Maybe you're right. To go for Paraya with community support should beat illegally use OGS with no support at all.